# How to make recycler view always visible even empty - Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerView. Its width match_parent / height wrap_content. I can not make it both match_parent since it takes only portion of the screen. So I need the area of that recycler been always visible even there are no items in it. Right now I have a background in it. And its visible only when at least 1 item in recycler. If recycler is empty the whole view is gone.

So is there a way to leave recycler with 0 items in it but at the same time the space that it holds be visible on the screen?

Comment: if recyclerView has 0 items add other view on same place if you want because It's a view itself and its visible after at-least one element in that view.

Comment: @SandeshKhutalSaheb no, another view is not solution I need. It must be recycler. Maybe there is a way to show invisible first item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution here is to set `minimumHeight` to some value. In this case the width will always be `match_parent` and you will have some invisible area that you can manipulate as you want

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting constant height to your RV? It should solve you

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"/>
```

If you need it to be scalable based on the screen size you can use ConstraintLayout to set a percentage of screen for its height:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.5"
/>
```

see here for more examples: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout#match_constraint-dimensions-added-in-1.1

Comment: I can't make it constant because it must dynamically scale on different screen sizes

Comment: the solution I need was minheight but your advice gave me an idea. So thank you